# How can I append to an array without overwriting or duplicating existing key?

Tags: php, arrays

The output I have is this:

```
[price_hidden_label] => 1
[categories] => Array
     (
        [0] => 26
      )
```

My current code to try and update is:

```
updateProduct($product->id, array('categories[108]'));
```

When I run this function, it overwrites the existing array, giving me an output like this:

```
[price_hidden_label] => 1
[categories] => Array
     (
        [0] => 108
      )
```

What I am trying to achieve would look like this:

```
[price_hidden_label] => 1
[categories] => Array
     (
        [0] => 26
        [1] => 108
      )
```

But.... in the event that 108 already exists, I would hope that it would just ignore it.  I don't want:

```
[price_hidden_label] => 1
[categories] => Array
     (
        [0] => 26
        [1] => 108
        [2] => 108
      )
```

Any idea how I do that?

Comment: Don't specify a key when appending to the array

Comment: Show the `updateProduct()` functions code.

Comment: public static function updateProduct($id, $object)
    {
        return self::updateResource('/products/' . $id, $object);
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can push elements to the array using

```
$arr[] = $new_var;
```

and check if a value already exists by

```
if(in_array($new_var, $arr))
```

In example (trying to follow your input-output):

```
$categories = array();
$categories[] = 26;
$input_value = 108;
if(!in_array($input_value, $categories)) {
  $categories[] = $input_value;
}
```

edit. in functions (my PHP is bit rusty, so there might be small tweaks that need to be done but you get the basic idea)

```
function updateProduct($arr, $input) {
  if(!in_array($input, $arr)) {
    $arr[] = $input;
  }
}
```

and then call it as

```
updateProduct($categories, $input_value);
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do that in context with the function?
updateProduct($product->id, array('categories[26]'));

Comment: My PHP is bit rusty and can't test right now, but you can get the idea from my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to add items to an array, and you can use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if it already exists, or you can use [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicates after your done the rest of your processing too.